# Django REST Framework allow only superusers to access api web view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-authentication

I'm using `Django 2.0` and `Django RESET Framework` to write `REST API` for my application.

I have configured following authentication methods

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

As of now, It allows all authenticated users to access `web api` view.

**What I want is to allow few users (probably superadmin users) to be able to access API from Session Authentication or from web browser by logging in.**

> Edit 2: contacts/views.py

```
class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user_id=self.request.user)
```

Comment: Can you add your contacts API view?

Comment: updated code in question

Comment: And you are sure that the browser request is using an authenticated user?

Comment: Got it, my configuration was misconfigured a little. But how to restrict web access to superadmin users only?

Comment: You'd have to create a custom middleware or build that into your views.  There shouldn't be any reason to limit a valid user to the same features based upon how their accessing the system.

Comment: You can do something cool here; give me a minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you can leverage `permission_classes` to do this. DRF's `Request` object remembers the authentication method that was used in an attribute called `_authenticator`. You can use this; and use the permission_classes to determine if the pair of (user, authenticator) has permission

```
class AdminAuthenticationPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    ADMIN_ONLY_AUTH_CLASSES = [rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication, rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication]

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user = request.user
        if user and user.is_authenticated():
            return user.is_superuser or \
                not any(isinstance(request._authenticator, x) for x in self.ADMIN_ONLY_AUTH_CLASSES) 
        return False

class ContactViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, AdminAuthenticationPermission,)
```

*Untested: but should work*

Comment: great it's working. only little modification is required. remove `()` from `is_authenticated()`. rest is good

Comment: Great to hear! That's a change in Django 1.10 I think; I am more used to 1.9 *Old habits*
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/1.10/#using-user-is-authenticated-and-user-is-anonymous-as-methods

Comment: Yes, I had used the same thing in version earlier to 1.10. But it will return `TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable` on `2.0`

Comment: I'd recommend updating your question to reflect the real underlying question and the corresponding answer for better future reference.

Comment: Remove `()` from end of `user.is_authenticated()` to fix TypeError @AnujTBE

Answer (score 14):

For Django 2 (Added in views.py)

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

class IsSuperUser(IsAdminUser):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return bool(request.user and request.user.is_superuser)

class ListSmth(ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsSuperUser,)
    ... Your code...
```

Comment: It would be better to inherit from `rest_framework.permissions.BasePermission` rather than `rest_framework.permissions.IsAdminUser`

Answer (score 5):

There is already inbuilt class called IsAdminUser, specify it as values to permission_classes property

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

class A:
    permission_classes = (IsAdminUser,)
```

this checks for the value

```
reques.user.is_staff == True
```

Comment: Note that (as you said) this checks for `is_staff` but the question specified super users.